# How to detect completion of task(installation) or new pop up dialog box

Tags: powershell

I had written a piece of code for the execution of a executable file that completes installation. The part of code where I am failing is that I had given time slots in seconds so that installation will finish within that duration and then take keystroke <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish the installation.

But it is not reliable at all because the installation speed depends upon the processor speed of machine and I have to use this code in different machines, so if the installation is taking 20 sec and I had given 15 seconds then it will take <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke before the completion of installation, which will click on "Cancel" in dialog box, and the installation is terminated without completion.

Is there any way that PowerShell can detect new popup dialog box or it will check whether the process is finished or not and then execute rest of the program?

```
$InstallFile = "D:\File for installation\folder\file.exe"
Start-Process $InstallFile
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;
$wshell.AppActivate($InstallFile)
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('')
Sleep 1
$wshell.Sendkeys('')
$wshell.SendKeys(" ")
$wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.SendKeys('')
Sleep -s 10
$wshell.SendKeys('')
Sleep -s 5
```

Comment: There is no generic solution to your problem. The best way to perform an unattended installation depends on what kind of installer you're running and what options that installer provides.

Comment: If the installer actually closes, or launches another process the closes you can write something to watch for the pid to go away.

Comment: Try running `file.exe /?` as this shows the command line options for most installers. If it's a commercial piece of software it's worth checking the manufacturers website to see if it supports unatended installation. Also googling 'software name unattended install' or 'software name silent install' is also worth a try.

Comment: You could look for the window by [p/invoking](http://www.pinvoke.net) `user32.dll` and using the methods for interacting with windows.

Comment: Actually I know the flow, but to detect the completion of operation or to detect new dialog pop up box is to be done. I will code the flow according to installation process, dat was not my actual concern.

Comment: I executed the code for silent installation and it worked also. but as i am installing a series of .exe files, the simple files are installed but for some files it is asking to click on radio button for  "I have read and  accept the license terms". How to select these options using Power Shell silent installation process. Please help me ....